# Using loop to determine which group of radios is "visible" and getting value of checked

Tags: javascript, typeerror, queryselector

i have select on my page that allows me to dynamically create rodio groups. When I change select options I remove old radios and append new ones to the same form. Now I need to read the value of the selected radio from the given group that is currently 'visible'. Radio groups have unique names. When I try execute a function with the code below i get Uncaught TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null. What I'm trying to get with these loops is to find the right radios group and get value (most important) from the selected one. If there is a simpler or diffrent way of doing this i'm open to good word, preferably in js.
This is what i have at this point of time

```
for (let key in glowne_klasy_radio) {
   let wartosc = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="' + key + '"]:checked').value; 
}
```

and also this

```
let group_radios_names = ["rzut", "podanie", "faul", "strata", "swobodny_ruch_pilki"];
for (let i = 0; i < group_radios_names.length; i++) {
    let wartosc = document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="' + group_radios_names[i] + '"]:checked').value;
}
```

Comment: What are `glowne_klasy_radio` and  `radios`?

Comment: Schould be same thing, misspaeling on my side, sorry, but i already have owerworked it. I made correction, but still not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by unchecked or non-existing radio buttons. It can easily be avoided by introducing a more tolerant way of asking for the `.value` attribute, see here:

```js
const radios = ["rzut", "podanie", "faul", "strata", "swobodny_ruch_pilki"];

function getAttr(obj,attr){
  return obj && obj.closest('div').style.display!=="none" && obj[attr]; }

function showHide(){
 document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]').forEach(q=>q.closest("div").style.display=Math.random()>.5?"":"none")
}

function getValues(){
const values={};
radios.forEach(r=>
 values[r]=getAttr(
document.querySelector('input[type="radio"][name="'+r+'"]:checked'),"value"));

console.log(values);
}

// Create radio buttons:
document.querySelector("div").innerHTML=radios.map(r=>'<div>'+r+':'+["A","B","C"].map(v=>'<br><label><input type="radio" name="'+r+'" value="'+v+'"> '+v+'</label>').join('')+'</div>').join("<hr>")
// Connect getValues function to button:
document.querySelectorAll("button").forEach((b,i)=>b.onclick=[showHide,getValues][i]);
```

```html
<button>show/hide some</button>
<button>check values</button>
<div style="height:650px"></div>
```

In this revised version of the script I also check for the visibility of a radio button group by looking at the parent's visibility:

```
obj.closest('div').style.display!=="none"
```

Only if this is `true` then then value of `obj` will be returned.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i definitely try to use it, especially the getValue() function which, i think, will be very helpful to my project. Btw. the problem was caused by unchecked or non-existing radio buttons. I posted already part of code that works for me at the moment, but i will keep in mind your solution to my question. Once more big thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Working code, i used element.querySelector, where let parent is parent element to my radio buttons.

```
let parent = document.querySelector("form[id='glowneRadios']");
let wartosc = parent.querySelector("input[type='radio']:checked").value;
```